# What unique delimiter to use rather than comma for separating

Tags: unique, separator

What delimiters can be used for separating a string by that delimiter rather than comma? since my string may contain a comma it is not always possible to separate using comma.

Comment: Only you can answer this question. You can use any character you like, as long as it makes sense for you. I might suggest `:`, but I don't know whether `:` is also possible within your strings.

Comment: i was thinking about some special characters that doesnot appear on keyboard but carry some ascii value, sorry fot that i didn't make it clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab and pipe are popular choices.

Answer (score 1):

personally, I'd use multiple characters to avoid any further complications.

something like: `<sp>` or `{[()]}` anything will do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

Anything that you could use as a delimiter in a string (ie, anything that it is possible to put into a string) may be part of that string (if it is not possible for it to be part of a string, then by definition you cannot use it as a delimiter, since delimiters must appear in the strings they are used to delimit portions of).

Perhaps your strings have some additional constraints placed upon them which would exclude certain bytes or characters, but only you can know that.

However, rather than using delimiters at all, you may want to use a different framing mechanism.  Consider using [netstrings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstring), for example.